# Parsing filenames with strsplit with variable number of #s

Tags: r

This is one of the problems where I'm stuck -- and frustrated because there must be another way:

What I am trying to achieve is to parse a lot of paths/filenames in R. The names are like this:

```
name1 <- "alpha234#181225235959/alpha234#181225235959_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
name2 <- "alpha123#181225235959#Tag/alpha123#181225235959#Tag_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
```

What I want is to strip off the bit before the first `/` and have one string corresponding to the stuff after `/` and until the first `#` and another to the stuff after the first `#` including any subsequent `#`s.

Here is what I do in the first step (until `/`):

```
splitname1 <- strsplit(name1, "/")
splitname1
[[1]]
[1] "alpha234#181225235959"        "alpha234#181225235959_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
```

and similarly for `name2`:

```
splitname2 <- strsplit(name2, "/")
splitname2
[[1]]
[1] "alpha123#181225235959#Tag"    "alpha123#181225235959#Tag_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
```

Here comes the problem. I use `strsplit` to deal with the "tail" from the above step:

```
strsplit(splitname1[[1]][2], "#")
[[1]]
[1] "alpha234"                           "181225235959_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"

strsplit(splitname2[[1]][2], "#")
[[1]]
[1] "alpha123"                  "181225235959"              "Tag_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
```

then I get either two strings or one. No amount of `paste` and what else I have considered has managed to coalesce the two strings into, in a way that can handle the two case (where it is needed or not).

There must be a better way.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub` is one option here:

```
name1 <- "alpha234#181225235959/alpha234#181225235959_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
sub("^.*?/(.*?)#.*$", "\\1", name1)
sub("^.*?/.*?#(.*)$", "\\1", name1)

[1] "alpha234"
[1] "181225235959_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want your output to look like, but I think `paste` with option `collapse = '#'` should help:

```
name1 <- "alpha234#181225235959/alpha234#181225235959_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
name2 <- "alpha123#181225235959#Tag/alpha123#181225235959#Tag_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"

name_list <- list(name1, name2)

lapply(name_list, function(x) {
  tmp <- strsplit(strsplit(x, "/")[[1]][2], "#")[[1]]
  c(tmp[1], paste(tmp[-1], collapse = "#"))
})
# [[1]]
# [1] "alpha234"                           "181225235959_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "alpha123"                               "181225235959#Tag_pic_4_1-8_9_19_90.dat"
```

Comment: Yes! This does what I would like it to do. I will spend a little while to ponder how it works.

Comment: The `lapply` statement just lets us test it on both names (made into a list) with the same function call.  As for the the rest of it - `tmp[1]` is the first entry in the output from strsplit, `tmp[-1]` is everything *but* the first entry.  Normally, the behavior of `paste` is to act on each element of a vector independently.  The option `collapse` tells it to merge them all into a single element (separated by whatever `collapse` is equal to (here, we replace the `#`).